# How do I create a svg drop shadow?

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

I've been using a bunch of tutorials to try to get my svg to have a drop shadow, but nothing is working!

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5nfdovg5/

This is what I did:

1. Created a **gradient fill** called **"Gradient-1"**. This **works**:

   - [image]
2. When I add the **dropshadow filter** (called **"dropshadow"**), it **only shows the shadow**, and none of the circle that is supposed to be on top.. just a black blurry circle:

   - [image]
3. The desired effect I would like is here:

   - [image] http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/arrow-with-dropshadow-lighter.svg

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the full markup:

```
<svg width="200" height="200">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="Gradient-1" x1="20%" y1="30%" x2="40%" y2="80%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#B8D0DE"></stop>            
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#73A2BD"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <filter id="dropshadow" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="130%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3">
                <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur">
                    <feComponentTransfer>
                        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.2"></feFuncA>
                    </feComponentTransfer>      
                    <feMerge>
                        <feMergeNode>
                            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
                        </feMergeNode>
                    </feMerge>
                </feOffset>
            </feGaussianBlur>
        </filter>
    </defs> 
    <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="25" filter="url(#dropshadow)" fill="url(#Gradient-1)"></circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have nested the feFilter elements which the example drop shadow code you link to in the question does not do. Unnesting makes things work as expected.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="Gradient-1" x1="20%" y1="30%" x2="40%" y2="80%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#B8D0DE"></stop>            
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#73A2BD"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <filter id="dropshadow" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="130%" width="130%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/>
            <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/>
            <feComponentTransfer>
                <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.2"></feFuncA>
            </feComponentTransfer>      
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs> 
    <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="25" filter="url(#dropshadow)" fill="url(#Gradient-1)"></circle>
</svg>
```